# Why Restrict Branch Deletion (Git)?

Tags: git

Why does git not allow you to delete branches that aren't in your current branch's ancestral history?

Is it because Git doesn't have access to them in its object storage?

Comment: Basically, it's a safety net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git does allow you to delete an unmerged branch by using `git branch -D <branch-name>`.  The reason it refuses when the branch you name is *not* merged (using lowercase `-d`), is to help reduce accidents where you throw away work you meant to merge.

Git *can* delete the branch, it just wants to be sure you're doing what you meant to do.

Comment: Also, don't get into the habit of using the `-D` flag willy-nilly, just to prevent Git from complaining about deleting unmerged branches. This flag, as well as `--hard` and `--force`/`-f`, should be used with caution.

Comment: And if you do deleted it by accident, you can peek into reflog to get the ref and get back to it.